# More succinct way to block a list of folders in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

I inherited a php website where the website root is in the top of the project. There is a list of files I don't want accessible from the web server. I setup my htaccess like so:

```
<LocationMatch "\/\.">
    Require all denied
</LocationMatch>

<DirectoryMatch "^tests/">
    Require all denied
</DirectoryMatch>

<DirectoryMatch "^src/">
    Require all denied
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Is there a more succinct way of saying here is a list of files, directories and locations and apply `Require all denied` to them? I don't just want one big nasty regex that will quickly become unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems **ModRewrite** has better syntax:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
RedirectMatch 404 /src
RedirectMatch 404 /tests
</IfModule>
```

One line per regex instead of three. I'm not sure about the performance differences.